# UITableView custom pull to refresh view does not show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I have the following code for my custom pull to refresh.

```
CGFloat customRefreshControlHeight = 50.0f;
CGFloat customRefreshControlWidth = 320.0f;
CGRect customRefreshControlFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                              -customRefreshControlHeight,
                                              customRefreshControlWidth,
                                              customRefreshControlHeight);

TestRefreshView *refreshView = [[TestRefreshView alloc] init];
refreshView.frame = customRefreshControlFrame;
self.testRefreshView = refreshView;

[self.tableView addSubview: self.testRefreshView];
```

However, this view does not show up when I pull down my table. Is there anything else I need to set up that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my worked example with custom `UIView` in `UIrefreshController`:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.frame = CGRectMake(x,
                                   y,
                                   self.refreshControl.bounds.size.width,
                                   self.refreshControl.bounds.size.height);

self.animIndView = [[AnimatorIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:self.refreshControl.frame];


[self.refreshControl addTarget:controller action:@selector(refrechLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[controller.refreshControl addSubview:self.animIndView];

[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```